# Pushing QT Project GIT with external libraries

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a QT project which uses openCV as external library, now I have to push this project in bitbucket.

I configured openCV in my local QT project as described in here : https://www.learnopencv.com/configuring-qt-for-opencv-on-osx/

But when someone will be pulling the project he/she will not go with the pain to link the QT project to the local paths, so how can I solve this problem of using external libraries when sent using QT.

Also, when I am pushing the project, do we need to send all the files? Many sources are saying that `.pro` goes in `.gitignore`, if that is so, then how will the person use the project directly in his QT Creator without a .pro file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would include the `.pro` file in git and add instructions on how to coop with external libraries (in a README file). Also [this projects](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Qt.gitignore), which contains a lot of `.gitignore` examples, does not ignore `.pro` files.

Possible solutions to avoid conflicts due to each user specifying its own external library location:

- Include another `.pri` file, containing the user dependent stuff. You can include in git a sample file, but the concrete implementation should be ignored by git.
- Define all the user dependent variables as optional arguments to qmake (Projects > Build > Build Steps > qmake > Additional arguments).